# Firebase Function throwing internal error when trying to call it from Unity

Tags: c#, node.js, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I work on a Unity C# app with Firebase Auth and Firebase Functions SDK installed.

I have three **callable** functions I developed and tested thanks to the Firebase emulators and they seem to work correctly.

I deployed my functions, launched the game in Unity Editor and I get an error whenever I call a function. The error is always `INTERNAL`.

I checked the logs on Google Cloud dashboard and it seems my function doesn't even run.

I put a breakpoint and decide to inspect the exception to gather some information.
However, there isn't any useful information other than `"One or more errors occurred"` and `"INTERNAL"`.

After numerous searches on Google/SO I've found two possible culprits :

- **Outdated SDK** -> I redownload latest SDK and re-import Firebase Auth and Firebase Functions into my Unity project --> same error.
- **Need to specify region** when getting the Functions instance if different than `us-central1`. According to the Google dashboard my functions are located in the `us-central1` region but just in case I specify it anyway --> same error.
  Then I notice that my actual Firebase project is in `europe-west3` so I specify this in my code when getting the instance of Firebase Functions or App --> still the same error.

Now I'm starting to doubt everything so I comment out `UseFunctionsEmulator()` and test again with the emulators -> it works fine.

What could be the problem?

Here is my `FirebaseManager.cs` that run before anything else:

```cs
public class FirebaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool gameQuitting = false;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();
    private static FirebaseManager _instance;
    public static FirebaseManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // [check if instance exists etc..]
        }
    }

    private FirebaseApp _app;

    private FirebaseAuth _auth;
    public FirebaseAuth Auth
    {
        get
        {
            if (_auth == null)
            {
                _auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(_app);
            }
            return _auth;
        }
    }

    private FirebaseUser _user;
    public FirebaseUser User
    {
        get
        {
            return _user;
        }
        set
        {
            _user = value;
        }
    }

    private FirebaseFunctions _func;
    public FirebaseFunctions Func
    {
        get
        {
            if (_func == null)
            {
                _func = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
            }
            return _func;
        }
    }

    // Events to subscribe to for this service
    public delegate void FirebaseInitialized();
    public static event FirebaseInitialized OnFirebaseInitialized;
    public static bool IsInitialized = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            _instance = this;
        }
        else { Destroy(this.gameObject); }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();
    }

    private void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        Debug.Log($"FirebaseManager.cs > INITIALIZING FIREBASE");
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
                // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
                _app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                // _app = FirebaseApp.GetInstance("europe-west3");

                // Create and hold a reference to FirebaseAuth
                _auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

                // Create and hold a reference to already logged in user (if any)
                _user = _auth.CurrentUser;

                // Create and hold a reference to Functions
                _func = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
                // _func = FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance, "europe-west3");
                // _func = FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance("europe-west3");
                // #if UNITY_EDITOR
                // _func.UseFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001"); // LOCAL FUNCS 
                // #endif

                // Subscribing to AuthStateChanged
                FirebaseManager.Instance.Auth.StateChanged += AuthService.AuthStateChanged;

                Debug.Log($"FirebaseManager.cs > INITIALIZED");
                IsInitialized = true;
                if (OnFirebaseInitialized != null) OnFirebaseInitialized.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "FirebaseManager.cs > Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
            }
        });
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (_auth != null) _auth = null;
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        FirebaseManager.Instance.Auth.StateChanged -= AuthService.AuthStateChanged;
        gameQuitting = true;
    }
}
```

I call my function from Unity like this :

```cs
HttpsCallableReference function = FirebaseManager.Instance.Func.GetHttpsCallable("GetAllCharacters");

// Call the function and extract the operation from the result.
function.CallAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread((task) =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        // this foreach is a debug attempt
        foreach (var e in task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Received Exception: {e.Message}");
        }

        foreach (var inner in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
        {
            if (inner is FunctionsException)
            {
               var e = (FunctionsException)inner;
               // Function error code, will be INTERNAL if the failure
               // was not handled properly in the function call.
               var code = e.ErrorCode;
               var message = e.Message;

               Debug.LogError($"Code: {code} // Message: {message}");

               // [Handle error]
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // [Handle data returned by the function]
    }
});
```

Finally, my Firebase Functions look like this: (`index.ts`)

```js
import * as Characters from "./Characters/Characters";

// CHARACTERS
export const CreateNewCharacter = Characters.CreateNewCharacter;
export const GetAllCharacters = Characters.GetAllCharacters;
export const DeleteCharacterByID = Characters.DeleteCharacterByID;
```

`Characters.ts`:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
// [custom classes imports]

// DATABASE INITIALIZATION
initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();
 
// CREATE NEW CHARACTER
export const CreateNewCharacter =
  functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>
  {
      ...
  });

// GET ALL CHARACTERS
export const GetAllCharacters =
  functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>
  {
      ...
  });

// DELETE CHARACTER BY ID
export const DeleteCharacterByID =
  functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>
  {
      ...
  });
```

In step-by-step debugging, here is what I find:
[image: Step-by-step debugging infos]

The `StackTrace` value is :

> "  at Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableReference.b__9_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[TResult] task) [0x00063] in <9b40ff23f61a4fcf97a5710997860279>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <4ba27aa039714eafa1e8892e51af2932>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <4ba27aa039714eafa1e8892e51af2932>:0 "

Comment: Unhandled exceptions server-side will be presented as "One or more errors occurred. (INTERNAL)" to clients. Check the logs for your Cloud Function instead.

Comment: Hey, In Google Cloud Functions dashboard, the logs showed that the functions weren't even called. There was no log other than the one related to deployment.
That's why I said I had no useful information as far as my skills can detect.
I've just made a try: redeploy my functions in `europe-west1` instead of default location `us-central1` and specify the new location when getting the Functions instance in C# Unity. Now it works but I'm not sure it is really a solution to why the error was thrown since by default it tries to reach functions in `us-central1` which was the default location set.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today. Deleting the function in the firebase console and redeploying it solved the issue for me, while still using the default instance.